# .attr() doesn't seem to be updating the attribute (class)

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="footer">
    <div class="follow-button" id="1">
        <a class="follow" id="follow">follow</a>
    </div>
    <small class="pull-right date">december 1st, 2018</small>
</div>
```

I have this setup in my HTML section, the main point of focus is the 'follow-button' div.

Below, I have a script written to change the button to read 'followed' as it is clicked, and then back to 'follow' should it be clicked again. But it doesn't seem to do that.

```
  <script>
    $('.follow-button').click(
      function() {
          if($('#follow').attr('class')=="follow")
          {
            $('#follow').attr('class', 'followed');
            $('#follow').text('followed');
          } else {
            $('#follow').attr('class', 'follow');
            $('#follow').text('follow');
          }
      }
    );
  </script>
```

I'm sure the issue is silly, but I must've done something because just a few iterations ago it was working fine (now I can't even get previous iterations to work).

Comment: [`.hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/), [`.addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/), [`.removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine. https://jsfiddle.net/1rxLjbnt/ Are there any errors in your browser's console?

Comment: I'm not sure the issue then, because it doesn't seem to be working -- even when I copy and paste the example codes provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `.addClass()` to add the class
2. Use `hasClass()` to check if the element has the class.
3. Use `.removeClass()` to remove class

```js
$('.follow-button').click(
  function() {
    if ($('#follow').hasClass("follow")) {
      $('#follow').removeClass('follow').addClass('followed').text('followed');

    } else {
      $('#follow').removeClass('followed').addClass('follow').text('follow');
    }
  }
);
```

```css
.followed {
  color: red
}

.follow {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="footer">
  <div class="follow-button" id="1">
    <a class="follow" id="follow">follow</a>
  </div>
  <small class="pull-right date">december 1st, 2018</small>
</div>
```

Multiple:

1. Use `data-*` instead of ID. ID should be unique on context

```js
$('.follow-button').click(
  function() {
    if ($(this).find('[data-id=follow]').hasClass("follow")) {
      $(this).find('[data-id=follow]').removeClass('follow').addClass('followed').text('followed');

    } else {
      $(this).find('[data-id=follow]').removeClass('followed').addClass('follow').text('follow');
    }
  }
);
```

```css
.followed {
  color: red
}

.follow {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="footer">
  <div class="follow-button" id="1">
    <a class="follow" data-id="follow">follow</a>
  </div>
  <small class="pull-right date">december 1st, 2018</small>
  
  
  
  
  <div class="follow-button" id="1">
    <a class="follow" data-id="follow">follow</a>
  </div>
  <small class="pull-right date">december 1st, 2018</small>
</div>
```

Comment: How about storing `$("#follow")` in a variable (or at least use chaining) instead of creating 4 distinct jQuery objects on every click

Comment: i will use chaining @Andreas

Comment: @guradio I've copied exactly your example and it still doesn't work. Any more suggestions as to why it is not working?

Comment: is your element `follow-button` auto generated? or you have multiple? if you have mutiple use class instead and use this context for element `#follow` @Mac

Comment: @guradio - .follow-button (multiple) is a class already, can explain the latter?

Answer (score 1):

JQuery provides several functions for working with classes, namely [`hasClass`](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) for checking whether or not an element has a particular class, [`addClass`](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/) for giving an element a new class, and [`removeClass`](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) for removing classes from elements. Using them instead of `attr` may solve your problem:

The [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) function can be used to make this cleaner:

```
if ($('#follow').hasClass("follow")) {
    $('#follow').toggleClass('followed').toggleClass('follow');
    $('#follow').text('followed');
} else {
    $('#follow').toggleClass('followed').toggleClass('follow');
    $('#follow').text('follow');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine but you can fine tune your code like below instead of "IF"

```
$('.follow-button').click(
  function() {
  var divfollow  =  $('#follow');  
  divfollow.hasClass("follow") ?       
  divfollow.removeClass('follow').addClass('followed').text('followed') :
  divfollow.removeClass('followed').addClass('follow').text('follow');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1rxLjbnt/2/